# File Upload Issue

Tags: php, file, upload

I am having trouble with this function,  I cannot seem to get my file to transfer -> when the file is uploaded into the final location  -> What have I missed:

**Problem Function:**

```
  public function imageUpload(){
            $this->bExisting = false;
            $location = "includes/images/Gallery/";
            $target = $_FILES['ImagePath']['name']; 
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImagePath']['tmp_name'], $location . $_FILES['ImagePath']['name'] );

  }
```

**Source View**

```
    <form id='imageUpload' action='addimage.php' method= 'post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 

<fieldset> 

<label for='ImageName'>Image:</label> 

<input type='text' name='ImageName' id='ImageName' value=''  onblur=''/> 

<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='1000000' /> 

<label for='ImagePath'>Image Path:</label> 

<input type='file' name='ImagePath' id='ImagePath' value='' onblur=''/><input name='submit' id = 'submit' type='submit' value='Image Upload' /> 

</fieldset>
```

**PHP View:**

```
<?php
ob_flush();
include('includes/session.php');

include('includes/header.php');

include('includes/class/class.form.php');

include('includes/class/class.page.php');


$iPageID = 1; 

if(isset($_GET["PageID"])){

    $iPageID = $_GET["PageID"];
}

$EditedPage = new Page();

$EditedPage->loadPage($iPageID);

$apageInformation = array(); // Information From DB Sticky
$apageInformation["Name"] = $EditedPage->getPageName();
$apageInformation["PageContent"] = $EditedPage->getPageContent();
$EditedPage->getPageContent();

//Sets form information

$Action = "editpage.php?PageID=".$iPageID; // Sets form file

$formEdit = new Form($Action, 'editPage','post','return CheckEditPage();','');

//Sets StickyData

$formEdit->setStickyData($apageInformation);

//Sets the Message

$Message = "";

//If it is set do below

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $formEdit->setStickyData($_POST);

    $formEdit->checkNotEmpty("Name");

    $formEdit->checkNotEmpty("PageContent");


    if($formEdit->getValid() == true){

            $EditedPage->setPageName = $database->escape_value($_POST["Name"]);

            $EditedPage->setPageContent = $database->escape_value($_POST["PageContent"]);

           $EditedPage->updatePage();

        $Message = "Page Updated";

    }else{

        $Message = "You Have An Error Mate";
    }
}


$formEdit->openFieldset();
$formEdit->makeInputBox("Name","Name","CheckInput(this.id);");
$formEdit->makeTextArea("Content", "PageContent", "20","70", "CheckInput(this.id);");
$formEdit->makeSubmitButton("submit","Edit Page");
$formEdit->closeFieldset();
?>
   <section class="left">

    <h1  class="Heading">Edit Page</h1>

        <p class="loginError"><?php echo $Message ?></p>

        <?php echo $formEdit->getHTML(); ?>

    </section> <!-- Section Left End -->

    <section class="right">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
    </section><!-- Section Right End -->


    <?php include('includes/footer.php')?>
```

Comment: Does your destination folder have correct permissions set for the file to be able to be copied there? Does print_r($_FILES) give you the information about the file being uploaded, or does it return nothing?

Comment: yes and yes returns correct data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you have to upload something to a new server, I would suggest to check some points:

- Make sure to chmod 777 (or make ir writeable) the directory you are going to use. (I would first use 777 and if it works try to put something more restricted)
- Check the phpinfo to know the correct paths, the post_max_size and the upload_max_filesize. (Usually it does nothing to put that in the html) You'll have to change it in your php.ini or sometimes you'll be allowed by your hosting provider to use the .htaccess

If these points are checked, I think that maybe it is the path. So I sometimes use this to get a path related to the script you are using. It is not very clean, but it works for me:

```
$thepath = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], 0, strrpos ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], "/")); 
$location="$thepath/../includes/images/Gallery/"; // if it is in the parent directory of your script, for example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting basename() around the second argument.

```
public function imageUpload(){
    $this->bExisting = false;
    $location = "includes/images/Gallery/";
    $target = $_FILES['ImagePath']['name']; 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImagePath']['tmp_name'], $location . basename($_FILES['ImagePath']['name']) );
}
```

Also, your variable *$target* is not being used.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="FILEGOESHERE.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="ImagePath" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: I was debugging when I posted this question hence $target not being used will try basename now

Comment: @Jess McKenzie  Could you post the HTML part of the form?  Are you sure that the method is being called?  Are the directory permissions set correctly?

Comment: I don't know what your $formEdit->getHTML() is doing, but by the looks of it you are most likely using the wrong HTML.  The HTML should look like what I have edited my answer to include.

Comment: Have included the source view

Comment: Try removing the value='' and onblur='' properties from the input file.  That sometimes causes problems too.